# How to detect if nothing is written in a form (using javascript)?

Tags: javascript, forms

this is my javascript code:

```
if (username==null || isBlank(username))
  {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="Please Fill Out Username Box".fontcolor("red");
  return false;
  }
 if (email==null || isBlank(email))
  {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="Please Fill Out Email Box".fontcolor("red");
  return false;
  }
  if (password==null || isBlank(password))
  {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="Enter Password".fontcolor("red");
  return false;
  }
```

When, I click the submit button and the forms are not clicked on at all, nothing is printed. What is the problem?

Comment: Use the jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: I think you meant `+` to concatenate your strings, not `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be what u want?

```
<form action="" name="someform">
    <input type="text" name="inputname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="warning"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function testForm ( e ) {
var inputname = this.inputname,
    warning = false;
    function isBlank ( elem ) {
        return elem.value === "";
    }
    // tests elems, you may put it into a loop
    if ( isBlank(inputname) ){
        warning = "<span style=\"color:red;\">some warning</span>";
    }
    // output
    if ( warning ){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML=warning;
    }
}
// bind
document.someform.onsubmit = testForm;
</script>
```